# Unable to use locators in @Test Junit Selenium web driver

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am new in JUnit Selenium, and I found problem.
I cannot find elements using locator in @Test method. I dont have predictive search when I type `driver.` I can if I type into `@Before`.

E.g I cant type

```
@Test
..
driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).sendKeys("blabla");
```

My class contains -

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

String baseURL = "https://www.google.com";
driver.get(baseURL);
}

@Test
public void test() {
driver.**___PROBLEM___**    

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}
```

[image: [eclipse - problem]]

Comment: If you hover over `driver` that is marked in red it will display an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you've declared

```
WebDriver driver;
```

locally within the setUp method which is also annotated using `@Before` in your case.

---

You shall move this to the class level and use further as -

```
public class SomeTest {

    WebDriver driver;

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ...
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        ...
        driver.get(baseURL);
   }

   @Test
   public void test() {
       driver.getTitle(); //just an example
   }

   .... // other methods

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working when I move WebDriver driver; into public class.
Why I cant put also System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe"); below WebDriver driver, for example

public class {
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
}

It is working only if I am setting property into Before...

Comment: @BabyBunny you can't put the `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");` statement in the class. Just imagine where would it be called from (what reference). It should be in a method.